# Was waiting for a wait that is over

Tags: past-tense

"It took a long time, but at last it arrived. Note that the seller explained (while I was waiting) why it **took** so long."

last time I asked this question I was answered that "took" implies that the wait was over and the thing was received . In this case it is not logical with the form "was waiting " because if I received the thing I am not waiting for it as  suggested by "was waiting"
Am I wrong?

Comment: Please use the ">" symbol to separate quoted text from your original text. I assume that only the first sentence in this post is quoted, right?

Comment: yes only the first sentence is quoted

Comment: But now you have the first two sentences quoted. And you haven't used [the ">" symbol](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), which greatly improves clarity.

Comment: no sorry  both sentences are quoted

Answer (score 0):

Note that the seller explained (while I was waiting) why it took so long.

That is correct and grammatical. *while I was waiting* is parenthetical in your version and does not affect the use of two verbs in the simple past.

Other ways to say it:

- Please note that the seller explained why it took so long while I was waiting.
- While I was waiting, please note that the seller explained why it took so long.

We generally say in addressing a reader or a person: Please note

"while I was waiting" is an explanation to the reader or interlocutor and does not affect the completed verb action.

- While I was waiting, the man started the car and sped off.

Comment: why does it not affect the verbs in the  simple past I don't understand very well sorry! Is it because it is parenthetical ?

Comment: @user5577 No, it doesn't affect them because it means: during the time that person was  doing something, A and B happened. These types of adverbial clauses are most often used with the simple past: I was waiting when he arrived. While I was waiting, he arrived.

Answer (score 0):

The natural version to me would be "The seller explained why it *was taking* so long" (if the wait was still going on).

Comment: i think like you. ln fact my sentence is  The seller explained whIle I was still waiting why it was taking so long.

Comment: @user5577 Your version does not work: "The seller explained whIle I was still waiting why it was taking so long" It has to be parenthetical like your original sentence **or** one of my versions. Kate has rewritten your sentence completely. It's fine but not the same thing.

Comment: "Please note (while I was waiting), the seller explained why it was taking so long " does it work ?Why must "while I was waiting" be parethetical?

Comment: _Please note that, while I was waiting, the seller had explained to me why it was taking so long._ I have used the past perfect tense because this happened _before_ the item arrived.

Comment: But"while I  was waiting" implies that I haven't received the item so past perfect does not seem obligatory.

Comment: "While I was waiting" implies that I **had not** received the item at the time I am talking about, though I did receive it later.

Comment: I don't get the logic here because the seller explained while I was waiting not before or after

Comment: While you were waiting for the item, obviously you had not yet received it!

Comment: Ok but past perfect is for the verb explained not received

Comment: The past perfect is used of an action that happened before another past action. You received the item in the past; _before_ that, you were waiting for it and the seller explained why it was taking so long.

Comment: but if I follow your logic, as I received the item I am not waiting so past perfect should be used also for wait

Comment: The past perfect doesn't _have_ to be used if the meaning is clear without it.

Comment: I suppose this is the same logic for taking ?So is PP mandatory for "explained" . Leaving "explained " in PS would it mean that the parcel has not arrived yet ?

Comment: No, because 'while I was waiting' implies that you are no longer waiting.

Comment: So I can leave explained in PS